# Java Outofmemory heap space error: How do I make a deque from a vector?

Tags: java, queue, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I'm new to Java and really need your help.

I am presently using a queue, a receiver thread puts data into this queue and the parser reads out of this.
But the problem is the receiver may receive at incredible peak speed, <del>eg. 3000/sec, while the parser only parses at 100/sec.</del>

> EDIT:I have checked, the queue first
>   stays at 100 or so, and after ten
>   seconds it starts to grow at 100 per
>   second, and crashes at 2000 or so.
>   Could it be possible that there is a
>   memory leak?

My code (in a tight loop) is

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
System.arraycopy(udpPacket.getData(), 0, data, 0, 1024);
queue.offer(data);
```

The heap is filled up too quickly, and I get an outofmemory exception. I guess the problem is that queue is made using a linked-list, and all the pointers must be saved in the heap.

I know a C version that does the same thing(using a buffer) but has much better performance, but because of deployment issues, we can only use Java.

Comment: Since the discussion is ongoing, you could specify what amout of data is received or streamed whether TCP or UDP is used and whats the frequency of transmission is. These informations would be necessary to suggest a best practice.

Comment: Looks like you are doing a lot of copying. You may want to wrap your data as input streams and pass that around instead.

Comment: @stacker: I have no control over the input, I can only control the sampling of the listener.

@Nick: Yeah, I'm doing a lot of copying, and I don't understand wrapping data as input streams. Could you please explain how and why input streams are better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you receive 3000/sec but only process 100/sec sooner or later you will run out of memory.
May I suggest you use more threads to do the parsing?

Concerning the queue, have a look at [LinkedBlockingDeque](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) and [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). There are both high-performance thread-safe queue implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but a stupid question, how do I parse one queue using multiple threads, I don't understand that.
Another problem is that I am running out of memory in matter of seconds, this is totally unacceptable...

Comment: I think that this idrosid means that you need to decouple the action of removing items from the queue from the processing of that item. So, you read the item from the queue and pass it off to one of a number of different threads to do the parsing. It allows you to process more than one queue item at a time. Having said that, I think it still will just defer the point at which problems occur rather than eliminate it.

Comment: Why does it defer the problem instead of eliminate it?

Answer (score 2):

Since data comes in 30 times faster than it is processed you may extend HeapSize using

`java -Xms<initial heap size> -Xmx<maximum heap size>` if the transmission is finished before your memory is exhausted.

- Or as youself suggested dump the data to disc and process delayed.
- Otherwise you would have to optimze your parser

Comment: Yeah, optimizing the parser, that's a good idea, because when the peak happens, the data is often homogeneous, so maybe I could keep statistics of top data and do some aggregation

Comment: @TiansHUo, this is not the answer. It may solve your problem now but you may have more problems in the future when even more data needs to be processed...

Comment: huh? Could you clarify what are the problems that will come up when more data needs to be processed. Or could you give a direction on how to improve the algorithm...

Comment: @TiansHUo, Imagine that you have an infinite source of data that needs constantly to be parsed. Increasing the memory won't solve the problem because the producer transfer rate is greater than the consumer's. The BlockingDeque suggested by me and @idrosid is a solution to this "memory leak" because it caches limited data in the queue halting the producer when the limit is reached.

Comment: You have mistaken the problem, normally, the consumer rate is bigger than the producer's, but sometimes the producer peaks.
Maybe putting data on disk is a way to implement a bigger cache?

Answer (score 1):

If the producer produces more data then the consumer can handle, then the data will start to accumulate and eventually you run into OutOfMemory problems. This will depend on (1) the rate difference between the producer and consumer, (2) the quantity of data you have to process.

I suggest you limit the number of items in the queue. Use a [`BlockingDeque`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html) -> [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) to limit the capacity of the queue and block your loop when the limit is reached. This way, the queue acts as a cache to the parser.

Comment: but the problem now is that the queue is only 2000 or so and I got a outofmemory exception, I guess there is a memory leak somewhere

Comment: Humm, that really is a small amount of data ... 1.9MB from my calculations .. shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Are there any (preferably opensource) tools you could suggest to help me see where the real problem is?

Answer (score 1):

> I guess the problem is that queue is made using a linked-list, and all the pointers must be saved in the heap.

I don't think so.  I think that the *real* problem is the mismatch between the rate at which your system gets input and the rate that it can process it.  Unless you can process at at least the average input rate, you will eventually run out of memory, no matter how you represent the queue.

You must either improve the processing rate, reduce the input rate or ... drop data.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to sample the data when queue gets too big, and save the sampling rate so we could simulate the original data.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `java`, you can use the `-Xmx` parameter to make more memory available to the virtual machine. For example, `java -Xmx512m` will allow the VM to allocate up to 512Mb of memory. (The default is fairly small).

But if you're allocating memory and filling up a list with data and never removing it, eventually you're going to run out of memory, no matter which language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory, the implementation of `ArrayDeque` (at least in Oracle JDK, I'm not sure about Android's) **seems** to never actually deallocate popped elements.

In other words, slots for popped elements are simply nulled. While elements added to the tail will make the "inner array" grow bigger for eternity, which will cause trouble sooner or later.

This code from Oracle JDK 1.8.0_144 :

```
public E pollFirst() {
    int h = head;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E result = (E) elements[h];
    // Element is null if deque empty
    if (result == null)
        return null;
    elements[h] = null;     // Must null out slot
    head = (h + 1) & (elements.length - 1);
    return result;
}
```

Spells trouble for me. :(

If my analysis is true, it seems that `ArrayDeque` is never intended to be a "real" FIFO queue, and is not suitable for such purpose. (Unfortunately I'm currently needing such purpose right now)

I'm currently investigating `LinkedList` instead (which also implements `Deque`).